# PHP Frameworks: Help Me Understand Common Statements

Tags: codeigniter, frameworks, symfony

I've been reading up on several PHP frameworks, and reduced my candidates to CodeIgniter and Symfony (I know there are many more).  Strongly leaning towards CodeIgniter, but have not 100% decided quite yet.

I'm not looking for a general "CodeIgniter vs Symfony" discussion.

One thing keeps coming up in comparisons: people say Symfony is for "advanced" coders and "bigger" sites; CodeIgniter is for "beginner" coders and "smaller" sites.  But I have yet to see any technical proof of this.  Everything I'm seeing about CodeIgniter feels right.

Can anyone explain structurally and technically where people are basing these statements on?

I want to understand all I can.  Once I make a decision, I want to focus my attention on one framework.

Thanks,
Matthew

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The biggest technical difference between CodeIgniter and Symfony (ver 1 and 2) is that Symfony is much easier to extend. This is especially true with Symfony2; you can replace entire parts of the framework as you see fit with custom code, or code from other libraries. You can even take any number of core components from Symfony2, and build your own framework on top of it. But, it's important to note that because Symfony is so 'advanced', it has a higher learning curve.

Here's how I see it: CodeIgniter is great when you have a small(ish) project that falls in the category of problems CodeIgniter is meant to solve. But when you want to do something *your* way, not CodeIgniter's way, you're going to have to fight the framework, which is never fun.

On the other hand if you're working on a Symfony2 project and want to do something your way, you can. It won't necessarily be quick, but it is possible. To me, that's the most important thing - you need to be able to make the framework do what you want it to do.

If you have time, read through the Symfony [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/index.html) and [cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/index.html) - they should give you an idea of what Symfony is capable of and how to customize and extend it.

> Everything I'm seeing about CodeIgniter feels right.

Then go with CodeIgniter. The most important thing is that you're comfortable with the framework/toolset. If you complete a project and find that it's lacking in features, you can always check out other frameworks.

Comment: "But when you want to do something your way, not CodeIgniter's way, you're going to have to fight the framework" - Could you elaboate on that? Afaik CI is one of the least restrictive frameworks around.

Comment: @stef When the time comes that you really wish the framework handled something differently, you run into a roadblock trying to get it to change. This is common amongst the smaller, 'quicker' frameworks. They tend to be more linear than Symfony and ZF. In Symfony and ZF, you can replace the internal workings of the framework with less friction.

Comment: Thanks for the terrific response.  I've spent a few more days intensely reading and re-reading documentation in both Symfony and CodeIgniter.  Judging from the documentation, I must say that BOTH projects are stellar. I'm still trying to better understand the whole question of "bigger" vs "smaller" projects.  I have to admit, I still can't find any clear (to me) explanation of why one framework or the other is better for "bigger" projects.  To hopefully understand this, the next thing I'm going to do is specify site elements, then see how it would be done in CodeIgniter vs Symfony.

Comment: Happy to help. To quickly elaborate, more extensible frameworks are better for bigger projects because the need for customizing the framework will come up more often in complex projects versus smaller or simpler ones. But your idea of running a comparison for a site's specs is a great idea, and it will definitely help decide. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend starting without a framework.  If you have been programming awhile and are comfortable with concepts like MVC and why you might implement your code in this pattern, then frameworks start to make more sense.

Frameworks are good for larger projects where there are many programmers and you need a consistent method of building application layers, like MVC.  The framework will likely provide some mechanism for object management and a consistent way for you to build application events (controller) and to separate the view logic from the model logic.

My PHP apps have been smaller, so I have not used any frameworks.  When I used to code in Coldfusion, on larger apps, I used MachII, Model-glue, Fusebox and ColdBox.  Each was good at something, each promoted consistency, but each had a lot of overhead and often times felt like it was in the way. I saw some developers get stuck **because** of the framework.
I did not start using any CF frameworks until I had build smaller apps without one.

If you like CodeIgniter better, for whatever your reasons, go with it.

Comment: I've spent a lot of time learning PHP, and I'm pretty good at it.  But I like how frameworks do help with some of the database connections, and especially how they have some crucial security elements already built in.

Answer (score -1):

CodeIgniter, because of the gentle learning curve and the great documentation. Give other frameworks a go if you ever feel you outgrow CI, which you may never do.